# Double does not work properly when executed

Tags: c++

I need good precision on the data, so I am using double to lable my definitions 
(*e.g.* `double x=M_PI`).
But whatever I do, double will not work, and only give me 5 points after decimal.

My IDE is geany, and I am currently using Raspberry Pi to program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout<<"Hello,World\n";
    double dxe=1.3558153152153215321755;
    cout<<dxe<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I need dxe to show most of its decimal place, but I am only getting 1.35582 on my terminal.

Comment: Note that 1.3558153152153215321755 is not representable in IEEE-754 64 bit binary floating point.